# rewriting `summarise_all` without deprecated `funs`, using Simple list and Auto-named list

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to count the number of `NA` values in each of 2 columns.

The code below works.

```
temp2 %>%
  select(c18basic, c18ipug) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

But I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

  # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

How can I rewrite my `summarise_all` line using each of the above techniques: `Simple list`  and `Auto named list`? Without using `summarise_all` as it seems to have been [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html).

Thanks.

Note: I find TidyVerse documentation very difficult to understand. If someone can point me to a resource that could help me figure out these things on my own, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Note: I figured out how to do it using Lambda:

```
temp2 %>%
  select(c18basic, c18ipug) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.x))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
   dplyr::summarize_all(list(sum= ~sum(is.na(.x), na.rm = T)))
```

Btw the `select()` is not necessary, you could write

```
temp2 %>%
  summarise(across(c(c18basic,c18ipug), ~ sum(is.na(.x))))
```

Ex.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars[1,1] <- NA
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(c(mpg ,cyl), list(sum= ~sum(is.na(.x), na.rm = T))))
```

Results in

```
mpg_sum cyl_sum
    1       0
```

I think you get the idea and see how easy the syntax is, when using more functions, e.g.

```
mtcars[1,1] <- NA
mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(c(mpg, cyl), list(
    Mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = T),
    SD = ~ sd(., na.rm = T),
    Min = ~ min(., na.rm = T),
    Max = ~ max(., na.rm = T),
    Obs. = ~ sum(!is.na(.))
  )))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. However, `summarise_all` has been superseded by `summarise` with helper functions: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html

Comment: Yes, that's why you are encouraged to combine `summarise` with `across()` :)

Comment: Got it, thanks. I thought that `dplyr::summarise(list(sum= ~sum(is.na(.x), na.rm = T)))` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? I added a MWE in my post.

Comment: `summarise(across...` does work, and your code for `summarize_all(list...` also works. In my previous comment I wrote that `summarise(list...` doesn't work. I suppose `summarise` (not `summarise_all`) doesn't go with `list`.